# How do I create a download link for qrcode in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, download, qr-code

I'm using [goqr.me](http://goqr.me/) api to create qrcode images. Now I want to create a download link for qrcode image.

I'm creating qrcode image this way:

```
function generateQrcode(data) {
    var params = {
        data: data,
        size: '200x200',
        margin: 0
    };

    // populate the preview box with the generate qrcode
    var dwnldUrl = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?'+$.param(params);
    previewBox.html('<img src="'+dwnldUrl+'" alt="qrcode-image"/>');
}
```

I want to have a download button for the qrcode image like this:

```
$('#qrcode-dwnld-btn').click(function() {
   // something to trigger download for the image ....    

}
```

Or is there anyother cross-browsing solution for this ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: just create an <a> tag whichs href = dwnlUrl?!

Comment: @Alex, yeah tried. but it does open in the same window, not downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. [goqr.me](http://goqr.me/) api provides the '**download**' parameter, we need to pass its value as '1' in the request to download image.

And then, we can set window location href to the resulted url.

```
$('#qrcode-dwnld-btn').click(function() {
    var qrCodeBaseUri = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?',
        params = {
            data: data,
            size: '200x200',
            margin: 0,
            // more configuration parameters ...
            download: 1
        };

    window.location.href = qrCodeBaseUri + $.param(params);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Downloadify (https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify) may do what you want.

Alternatively, I found adding the download="filename.ext" to your  tag may work, but it is a HTML5 feature:

```
<a href="url/to/your/qrcode" download="filename.ext"><img src="url/to/your/qrcode" /></a>
```

Of course substituting **filename.ext** with something that makes more sense.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help. Yeah it works but I want a cross-browser solution. As you said its HTML5, doesn't work in IE at all.

Comment: Apparently you can work around it not working in browsers older than IE10, this may help: http://paxcel.net/blog/savedownload-file-using-html5-javascript-the-download-attribute-2/